# Scrolling div items into view on keypress

Tags: angular

I have the following scrolling div, which I want to scroll when pressing the up and down arrows keys. The problem is when the selection get´s out of view I want to scroll the div accordingly. I added a [focused] attribute to the div element only for demonstration purposes, I was hoping I could databind to a focused attribute via Angular2.

```
<div class="scrolling-div">
    <div *ngFor="let item of Items; let i = index" [focused]="i === currentIndex">
         {{item.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Once I detect a arrow keypress the currentIndex is incremented or decremented. The problem is I want to set the focus to the current item such that the div get´s scrolled accordingly.

Is there a way to bind each item to the focus such that it get´s scrolled into view? Maybe there is a different solution to this problem.

Comment: Why do you use `[focused]`? Is that an attribute directive you defined or the html focused attribute (mainly used for input fields)

Comment: Sorry about that it's only a wish :) I updated the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's an example of a `focused` directive that will do the work:

```
import {Directive, Input, Renderer, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[focused]'
})
export class FocusedDirective {
  @Input()
  set focused(value: boolean){
    if(value){
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scrollIntoViewIfNeeded');
    }
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){}
}
```

If you want it to scroll to the top (and not just become visible), replace `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` with `scrollIntoView`.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gSFdUy0eplAuKEPLLGNH?p=preview) of a very basic working example. Note that I didn't do range checking and the like, just showed basic functionality

Comment: why have to use renderer? `this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()` works just fine for me.

Comment: It serves as an abstraction layer and enables running in various environments. Have a look at the explanation here: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-explore-the-renderer-service-e43ef673b26c

Comment: Thanks, you were right, it works under Chrome, but getting error under Edge.

Comment: When you use the element directly or also when using renderer?

Comment: When using element directly

Comment: and when you use the renderer?

Comment: as I've seen: selector should have same name as the set